# Blender 2.8 Object first time settings

Tags: modeling

I need to find these settings in blender 2.8. When you add new object (Blender 2.79) you have this object settings, down left. But in version 2.8 I can't find it.

I need to change sphere segments in blender 2.8.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Blender 2.79 object setting]

Comment: Very hard to answer this question.  Been building the 2.8 branch nightly, and in latest it's [hard to miss it](http://pasteall.org/pic/ac3df829fff0731d8512242aab25cdf8).  Suggest waiting till a release candidate pops up before asking about 2.8.

Comment: Nice thank you.I didn't have the latest build download. Thanks.

Comment: In any case, you can bring that window up with F6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about unreleased experimental development software

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: I'm voting to reopen this, because 2.8 has been released

Comment: Why, what is there to gain? It is already answered, and there already are countless duplicates around https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126568/how-to-reduce-poly-number-when-you-start-creating-object-in-2-8/126570#comment219685_126570 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/where-is-the-operator-panel-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things are a changin in 2.8

The creation parameters menu, for now, is at the bottom of the screen as a fixed window (supposedly will become a floating one at some point).

[image]