# How to reduce poly number when you start creating object in 2.8?

Tags: polycount

In Blender 2.79, there's an option to reduce poly number of your object, the option appears when you first create it.

[image]

But now I've moved on to Blender 2.8 and can't find it, Where is it?

[image]

Comment: Another way is to press F6

Comment: I just tried it. F6 did nothing.

Comment: That's weird, I just created a new object, pressed F6 key, and the parameters menu popped up, actually since I switched to 2.8 this is how I use it, I find the new placement of parameters hard to spot!

Comment: Seriously, dude. It did nothing.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What OS are you using? What version of Blender 2.80?

Comment: All right, I know what's the problem, go to Edit > Preferences > Input, at the top you'll see Blender in a drop down menu, choose Blender 27X, and remember to save preferences, that was the first thing I did when I installed Blender 2.8, I totally forgot about it, for some reason they deprecated the F6 shortcut in 2.8, along with other things, don't ask why, I still don't get why they removed half the stuff they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

Hope you can see it there.

Comment: I like the size of that arrow a lot. +1

Comment: Glad you like it. Had to be extra extra noticeable this time so I went for triple size of my usual enormously oversized extra noticeable red arrow. :D

Comment: I find it hard to see what you're actually pointing at.

Comment: I did my best though. I think I will accept this failure of mine and learn to live with it eventually. :)

Comment: Human shall learn to live with their mistakes. Especially if not much people want to live with you.

Comment: :D ............

Comment: How are you supposed to do if you want to change the number of segments after creation of the object ?

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know, that dialog is called "Adjust Last Operation" and exists for a lot of operations, not only adding meshes.

If for some reason you can't see it, you can summon it from the Blender window's header > *Edit* > *Adjust Last Operation*.

People familiar with the pre-2.80 keymap might prefer assigning <kbd>F6</kbd> as a shortcut for it. To add a shortcut: right click on the menu option, "Assign shortcut", hover on the little box, press the preferred key.

[image]