# Where is major segment in blender 2.9x

Tags: modeling

I'm a new for blender
i'm watching on youtube about adjust major segment but i find not found this menu on blender 2.90.1
Where is major segment in blender 2.9x

Comment: Hi! What do you mean exactly by "adjust major segment"? Could you provide more info?

Comment: This is version 2.8 and now 2.9 it seem change again
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111079/blender-2-8-object-first-time-settings

Comment: Ah! If you mean the Redo Panel, it didn't change from 2.8 to 2.9. It still appears in the bottom left part of the *3D Viewport* window in which you executed the command.

Comment: hi all 
plz advice me , why this menu disappear on my blender ?

https://www.img.in.th/image/h60Stu

Answer (score 4):

When you add a torus, you have the Adjust Last Operation panel floating in the 3d view. It may be collapsed so just expand it.

[image]

The panel is only available after an operation and once you perform another operation it disapears.

These settings are specific to Add torus operation, other operations will have other kinds of settings in the same panel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but why my menu disappear ?
https://www.img.in.th/image/h60Stu

Comment: Yes, it does dissapear when you do another operation. It is available temporarily only right after the operation.

Comment: that it mean i can change this only one time ?

Comment: You can change it as many times as you want before you perform another operation, but then the settings are finalised and are no longer available.

Comment: thank a lot, i got it. :)

Comment: Can I open it again?